# LINQ Select and Convert Entites to ViewModels

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am not new to Linq but for any reason i cant solve this problem.

Lets say i have the following Models. Clearly this are sample models.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Toys> Toys { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

public class Toys
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

What i want is to convert them into ViewModels. Here how my ViewModels are defined

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ToysViewModel> Toys { get; set; }
}

public class ToysViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

#### My Problem

How can i select and convert my models into the viewModels. 
Here is what i already have tried.

```
var q = from p in dbContext.Parents
        where p.Id = 123
        select new ParentViewModel
        {
           Id = p.Id,
           Children = ???
        };
```

How can get the List of Children and their Toys ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes but i want them as the List<ChildViewModel> and not List<Children>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the relations are properly modeled in the database, then

```
select new ParentViewModel
{
   Id = p.Id,
   Children = p.Children.Select(c => new ChildViewModel {
       Id = c.Id,
       Toys = c.Toys.Select(t => new ToyViewModel { ... }).ToList()
   }).ToList()
};
```

Comment: And constructors on the ViewModels can make this a lot more readable.

Comment: I get a exception at runtime. I only get the german error message :( But basicly it says that Linq to Entites doesnt know the method 

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[....ViewModel.ChildViewModel] ToList[ChildViewModel](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[....ViewModel.ChildViewModel])

Comment: @dknaack: Not really, try editing the question and providing more code.

Comment: Ok, i will... takes a few minutes

Comment: Damn, i can't reproduce the exception with my test code. :( Anyway, your answer is right.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I can't figure how to use contructors here. When I try, I get the "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities" exception. (yep I noticed that this was posted in 2012...)

Comment: No, you can't use a ctor directly here. Dn't know why I said  that. Still, if you want to use them, `.AsEnumerable().Select(...)` ought to work. When you use all/most columns (properties) there shouldn't be a big diff in performance.

Answer (score 3):

For clarity I would prefer to break it down into functions like this:

```
public static ParentViewModel AsViewModel(Parent parent)
{
    var childViewModels = parent.Children.Select(AsViewModel).ToList();
    return new ParentViewModel { Id = parent.Id, Children = childViewModels };
}

public static ChildViewModel AsViewModel(Child child)
{
    var toyViewModels = child.Toys.Select(AsViewModel).ToList();
    return new ChildViewModel { Id = child.Id, Toys = toyViewModels };
}

public static ToyViewModel AsViewModel(Toy toy)
{
    return new ToyViewModel { Id = toy.Id, Name = toy.Name };
}
```

Then it can be used like so:

```
var q = dbContext.Parents.Where(p => p.Id == 123).Select(AsViewModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using some auto-mapping tool like [Automampper](http://automapper.org/).

Define somewhere mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, ParentViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Child, ChildViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Toys, ToysViewModel>();
```

And your code

```
 Parent parent = GetParentById(123); // use LINQ to get parent
 ParentViewModel pvm = Mapper.Map<ParentViewModel>(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)** to convert my entites to models. It supports collections nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var q = from p in dbContext.Parents
    where p.Id = 123
    select new ParentViewModel
    {
       Id = p.Id,
       Children = p.Children.Select(c => new ChildViewModel
       {
           Id = c.Id,
           Toys = c.Toys.Select(t => new ToysViewModel
           {
               Id = t.Id
           }).ToList()
       }).ToList()
    };
```

Comment: I get a exception at runtime. I only get the german error message :( But basicly it says that Linq to Entites doesnt know the method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[....ViewModel.ChildViewModel] ToList[ChildViewModel](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[....ViewModel.Ch‌​‌​ildViewModel]) – –

Answer (score 0):

To keep your own style of writings:

```
var q = from p in dbContext.Parents
    where p.Id == 123
    select new ParentViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Children = (from c in p.Children
                    select new ChildViewModel()
                    {
                        Id = c.Id,
                        Toys = (from t in c.Toys
                                select new ToyViewModel() 
                                {
                                    Id = t.Id,
                                    Name = t.Name
                                }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
    };
```

And I would call `Toy` instead of `Toys` and `ToyViewModel` instead of `ToysViewModel`